# How to show container on click with Localstorage?

Tags: javascript, css, local-storage

I'm trying to show container on click with localstorage. I mean that when you click the button, CSS classess:`is-hidden` and `is-visible` will be saved and remembered by browser.

This is my code:

```
var comments = document.getElementById("js-comments");
if (comments) {
    comments.addEventListener("click", function() {
        localStorage.setItem('comments', 'true');
        comments.classList.add("is-hidden");
        var container = document.getElementById("js-comments__inner");
        container.classList.add("is-visible");
        if (localStorage.getItem('comments') == 'true') {
            container.classList.add("is-visible");
        }
    });
}
```

HTML markup:

```
<div class="comments">
                    <button class="comments__button" id="js-comments">Load comments</button>
                    <div class="comments__inner" id="js-comments__inner">
                        <h3  class="h4">Comments</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Idea is: when you click on the `button` and the `comments__inner` elements then they receive the CSS clasess.

Comment: Your code suggests that you want to hide the `js-comments` _every single time_ somebody clicks that element. Is that what you’re trying to achieve?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? I assume you want to *toggle* the visibility? (and save the state so it is retained beyond page loads?)

Comment: please provide some html snippet also or describe elements

Comment: Why do you need two different classes for this? There is no third state, so one class that makes an element go into the opposite of the _default_ state should do for most use cases.

Comment: `<div class="comments">
                    <button class="comments__button" id="js-comments">Load comments</button>
                    <div class="comments__inner post__inner" id="js-comments__inner">
                        <h3  class="h4">Comments</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>